# Extjs 4.1 - CheckboxModel within checkcolumn in grid Fail?

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid, extjs4.1

I try to work with checkboxmodel and checkcolumn in **http://jsfiddle.net/Veb7Q/**. But i found a bug. 

That is when i click checkboxmodel after i click checkcolumn I see no row is selected but when i click my button to get selected, It have ?

Here is my button to get selection

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        visible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            //alert('You clicked the button!');
            var s = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
            Ext.each(s, function (item) {
                alert(item.data.name);
            });
        }
    });
```

Follow my step you will see a bug

**step 1:** click checkboxmodel and you will see like below

[image]

**step 2:** click Active column and you will see like below
[image]

**step 3:** click button "Click me" and you will see a bug like (no selection here? ). How to fix this bug. Thanks

[image]

Comment: The problem is with "checkcolumn" bind with grid.... trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it..

Just add "stopSelection : false" in your checkcolumn xtype @trungkien

```
, {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            text: 'Active',
            dataIndex: 'active',
            stopSelection : false,
            align: 'center',
            defaultType: 'boolean'
        }
```

I hope this will work.